# Deploying a React TypeScript app to AWS S3?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

The deployment in AWS S3 was written in JS I am doing in TypeScript.What code should I add for TypeScript to make it work.

**1)There are downloaded files with ts extension**
[image]

**2)But they don't load when the page loads**
[image]

**3)white page**
[image]
**4)Through github everything is fine**
[image]

Comment: Web browsers don't support Typescript. You have to transpile your TypeScript code to JavaScript before deploying it.

Comment: Thank you, I found where the mistake was.

Answer (score 1):

**This was a .ts and should be a .js**
[image]